# I want to play Oblivion. What mods do I need?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I played Oblivion when it first came out in 2004. By played I meant I did around 3 hours before getting bored.

It seemed to lack... impetus, and the leveling system is, as everyone knows, messed up.

What are the mods that would make Oblivion a worthwhile game to play in 2011?

Comment: You don't *need* any mods (and the way you've phrased your question seems highly argumentative, which means closure). You're basically asking for a "mod-rec", and since "game-rec" was decided to not fall within our scope, I doubt "mod-rec" will do much better.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer waaa. This is not something that will turn into a flame war. Just give me a list of mods and I'll try them all.

Comment: You could try rephrasing the question to ask for mods that perform a specific function, such as changing the leveling system.

Comment: Never play without the [Unofficial Oblivion Patch](http://oblivion.nexusmods.com/mods/5296), it fixes thousands of bugs - many of which are quest and game-breaking (many are just annoying). Also, I highly recommend [Realistic Leveling](http://oblivion.nexusmods.com/mods/13879) too. It will save you from headaches and need for micromanagement related to Oblivion's quirky leveling system. Also, check out the mods in this post: http://www.reddit.com/r/oblivion/comments/n5er2/hey_roblivion_ive_had_this_game_for_awhile_and_i/

Comment: @Mark, Raven Dreamer's right. You don't need any mods, so it isn't important. If you're trying to ask is what mods are useful for gameplay since you want to player oblivion, then edit the question please. Lucky for you I didn't flag this.

Answer (score 3):

[Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul](http://www.oscurogamedesign.com/down-game-ooo-high.html) is a massive mod that completely removed the automatic difficulty scaling, replacing all spawns in the game with fixed-level monsters and loot. Your question seems to indicate that was your biggest complaint with the game, so you should find OOO right up your alley.

Comment: Will this tell you where to go? Since Oblivion is non linear I believe, setting the fixed level monsters should make some normally accessible places too difficult in the beginning. Or am I just supposed to explore a place and run away if it's too hard?

Comment: The difficulty curve generally follows the areas the main storyline takes you to, but it's been a while so I don't quite remember.

Comment: There is also a cave just outside the Imperial City (Dznot Cave, I think?) with high-level amazons. You really need to get to know your quicksave key.